# On the existence of a certain set of subspaces of $\mathbb R^4$.

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I wonder if there exists $V_1, ..., V_4$ subspaces of $\mathbb R^4$ such that $\dim V_i=2$ for any $i$ and $V_i+V_j=\mathbb R^4$ whenever $i\neq j$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, let $\{e_i\}$ be a basis.

$V_1 = \langle  e_1, e_2 \rangle$

$V_2 = \langle  e_3, e_4 \rangle$

$V_3 = \langle  e_1+e_3, e_2-e_4 \rangle$

$V_4 = \langle  e_1+e_4, e_2+e_3 \rangle$

Comment: Could you please explain these angular brackets? It is the span or so?

Comment: Yes, denotes the space spanned by what's inside

Comment: The above construction will work in any vector space except in characteristic 2, where the space generated by $V_3$ and $V_4$ is of dimension only 3. I think it should be possible to remove this difficulty.